# Can' create unique constraint in ms sql server. Get an error in expression field

Tags: sql, unique-constraint

I need create a unique constraint, because my column in database must consists of unique values. Type is varchar. Below is my expression:

```
      ALTER TABLE Visit ADD CONSTRAINT constr1 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (time)
```

But get an error, that this expression is wrong

Could you help me?

Comment: What's the exact text of the error?

Comment: Error validating constraint CK_Visit

Answer (score 1):

According to this [SQL Server 2005 How Create a Unique Constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint) the first answer says that you need a column name, but I see you have written `time` which is a keyword. If you have a column named `time`, write `[time]` instead :)

Comment: Wow, thanks, your link helped me. First time I tried like this: right click -> add constraint, and into expression field tried write my previous variant. But how to use this constraint in c# code?? How to execute it from code? Is it possible?

Comment: If my answer helped, voting up and marking as an answer is appreciated.

About your further question: constraints are in mssql and not in c# side. You can, however, check, whether some query has updated/inserted rows and this way know whether constraint had affected your data. Otherwise, I see no other way how to use it in c# code :)

Comment: sorry but I can't vote. When I try to do it, I get a message: Vote Up requires 15 reputation...What does it mean? I am a newer on this forum...

Comment: You get points for answering, commenting, basically - helping others. If you had points and voted up my answer, I would get points added to my current pile which would mean I am a helpful person :) Moreover, you can spend points by creating an extra reward (thus - more attention and higher chance to get it answered by someone) on some question :)