# SQL Server CHECK Constraint - Ensure no duplicates on text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to add some sort of constraint on my table column. I need to make sure that the user does not enter, manually or otherwise, the same text in more than one row of the table. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use some type of [unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) or, of course, the primary key would work as well.  For example:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT UK_MyUniqueConstraint UNIQUE (MyColumn)
```

There are other methods of creating this [discussed on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint) as well.