# UNIQUE fields in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints

I am writing a forum for the company I work for. I am in the middle of creating the database tables and I have set up all my primary keys but I want user_name to be unique so no two users can have the same username when registering.

Could someone shed some light on how this can be done, I have a basic level of knowledge when it comes to SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a unique ***Index*** on user_name.

In SQL Management Studio:

1. right click the Table in question, left click Design
2. Right click on some white-space (or the junction of the design table), left click Indexes/Keys
3. Click the Add button to create a new index
4. Make sure the new one is selected in the list on the left
5. Click the Triple dot button in the value area for the columns property of the index
6. Select user_name from the drop-down box
7. Click OK
8. Set **Is Unique** to **True**
9. Click Close
10. Press Ctrl+S to save (will run the appropriate background scripts)

Update:

From [SQL Server 2005 How Create a Unique Constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint)

> In SQL Server Management Studio Express:
>
> 1. Right-click table, choose Modify
> 2. Right-click field, choose Indexes/Keys...
> 3. Click Add
> 4. For Columns, select the field name you want to be unique.
> 5. ***For Type, choose Unique Key.***
> 6. Click Close, Save the table.

Comment: I'm hedging my bets on GUI instructions... :)

Comment: I can only open table or modify. If I right-click the User_name field and go to indexes/keys, the only entry in there is my PK. So do I need to add a new one and select user_name?

Comment: Do you happen to know a different way as I don't get an option called 'Is Unique'is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Satish's answer may be more applicable in such a case then, DDL. I'm not sure why 'Is Unique' is missing, what version/edition of SQL Server / SQL Management studio are you running?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2005 and therefore can only assume that it's also SQL Management Studio 2005 too.

Comment: Any luck with trying the "SQL Server 2005 How Create a Unique Constraint" steps above?

Comment: Yes I have managed to sort it out, thank you ever so much for everyones help. I know your probably all pretty frustrated at how easy this was.

Comment: Care to tick my answer as the answer?

Comment: I do apologise mate, I wasn't in work last week from the 23rd. Your answer was correct and it's now working great!

Answer (score 0):

create unique index.  That will force unique values for that column.

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)

Comment: I would have beaten you to be first answerer, but the answer is so short I had to lengthen it a few times, and then I had to fill out a captcha!

Comment: I have seen, while I have been creating them in SQL server management studio that you can do it by right-clicking on the field and going to indexes/keys I think it is but then I don't know the syntax to enter to make the field unique.