# How to prevent from duplicates in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am new to SQL Server. I have created a DB in Access and defined my relationships there. After this, I have used SQL Server Import and Export Data tool to convert the DB and use in SQL Server. My table structure is as follows:

```
Student            Course             Course-Module    Module          
-------------      -------------      -------------    -------------
TagID (PK)         CourseID (PK)      CourseID (FK)    ModuleID (PK)
StudentName        CourseName         ModuleID (FK)    ModuleName
CourseID                                                             

Module-Session     Session            Atendance
--------------     --------------     --------------
ModuleID  (FK)     SessionID (PK)     TagID     (FK)
SessionID (FK)     SessionName        SessionID (FK)       
                   SessionDate        ScanningTime
                   SessionTimeStart
                   SessionTimeEnd
```

I have developed a query that will find a current `SessionID` for the given `TagID` insert the result into `Attendance` table along with the time of insertion.

My query is (VS C# syntax)

```
string query = @"INSERT INTO Attendance " +
               "SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, " +
               " @todaysDate " +
               " AS ScanningTime " +
               " FROM (((Student s " +
               " LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " +
               " LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON cm.ModuleID = ms.ModuleID) " +
               " LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " +
               " WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo " +
               " AND se.SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date) " +
               " AND se.SessionTimeStart <= @Plus30Min " +
               " AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= @Plus30Min ";
```

Query runs, and produce expected results and inserts them to `Attendance` table.

My problem is that I would like to make fields `TagID` and `SessionID` of `Attendance` table to be unique, i.e I want one student to register for particular session only ONCE, not multiple times as it is possible now.

**EDIT:**

An example of my problem. Student scans a tag and the result is placed in Attendance table:

```
Attendance
--------------------------------------
TagID      SessionID      ScanningTime
4820427      Test1    2013-08-13 15:10:02.590
```

After a few second, student tries to scan again, and the result is added as new record

```
Attendance
--------------------------------------
TagID      SessionID      ScanningTime
4820427      Test1    2013-08-13 15:10:02.590
4820427      Test1    2013-08-13 15:10:09.103
```

This is want I want to avoid. I just want to allow the student to scan ONCE (So it should allow only for one record with combination of 4820427 and Test1). If he will try to do it again, the error message should pop up.

Comment: So you want to change the `INSERT` that only unique primary keys are inserted? What kind of duplicates do you have, show some sample data and the expected result (and remove the C# code from the query, otherwise we cannot copy&paste it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a [UNIQUE constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint)... that is exactly what they're for.

```
ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    TagID,
    SessionID
)
```

Comment: could you please elaborate? I'm totally new to SQL

Comment: It seams like this should help. Is it possible to create Unique constraint on two collumns together?

Answer (score 2):

make TagID and SessionID as a primarykey, a composite key.

```
open design view,
choose the two fk keys.
and make as primarykey.
```

Comment: But OP has aready noted `PK` for both, so i assume that they are already primary keys.

Comment: Attendance table has 2 foreign keys, not primary

Comment: in design view I'm able to set only 1 primary key of Attendance table

Comment: you should be able to check more than one field, what version you use? otherwise use sql for making unique constraints primary key clustred. I will put code in answer too.