# How to avoid duplicate entries without primary key and unique key?

Tags: mysql

I want to know whether it is possible to avoid duplicate entries or data without any keys or group by statement

Comment: can you provide some examples?

Comment: By just simply not inserting dupe entries?

Comment: I had redesigned a table by merging 4 tables into 2 tables the problem now is primary keys used already for preventing duplication is shorted out hence the total functionality is becoming disaster duplication of entries while fetching the data from DB I am using  inner join to fetch the data

Comment: Hence the question Is there is any other method to prevent duplicates???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to suppress duplicates when querying, use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

If you want to avoid putting duplicates *into* a table, just don't insert records that are already there.  It doesn't matter whether you have a primary/unique key:  those will make the database not *allow* duplicate records, but it's still up to you to avoid *trying* to insert duplicates (assuming you want your queries to succeed).

You can use `SELECT` to find whether a record already exists before trying to insert it.  Or, if you want to be fancy, you can insert the new records into a temporary table, use `DELETE` to remove any that are already present in the real table, then use `INSERT ... SELECT` to copy the remaining records from the temporary table into the real one.

Answer (score 2):

Create Unique key constrait.

```
ALTER TABLE Comment ADD CONSTRAINT uc_Comment UNIQUE (CommentId, Comment)
```

In above case Comment duplication will not be done as we are creating the unique combination of COmmentId and Comment.

Hope this helps.

More info : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp OR

[SQL Server 2005 How Create a Unique Constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64981/sql-server-2005-how-create-a-unique-constraint)